# Length of month name is not correct Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

It was a immediate project done in Sep,2013, went in without issues. Oracle was back-end. am not much into oracle or any db. problem is, there was a logic which we had to implement with an SQL . that is to find the length of the month in the date. It was working , and am not sure, may be i was wrong or misled, the length looked strange. after some research with trial n errors, found it the length was always the same? am I doing something wrong please? here is my very simple SQL function call.

```
LENGTH(TO_CHAR(proj_created_date,'MONTH'))
```

It is constantly returning 9

I tried `LENGTHB()` function after some research, it was still the same? I believe it appends some spaces, and ofcourse `TRIM()` fixed it. but why should I trim? Should I not convert date into a String? please help me out!

Also tried both Oracle 10g and 11g jdbc URLs....

thanks.

Comment: it is Simple.. it is like the maximum month length is returned.. and it is September's .. use Format models..(FM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below.

```
LENGTH(TO_CHAR(proj_created_date,'FMMONTH'))
```

Further explanation [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90125/sql_elements4.htm)!

it is not just with Month, also with week name and even the Day number, a zero will be appended to a Day number. Say "`01`" and not "`1`". Use the format models as per your requirement. It applies till Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 0):

[As documentation says](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php) `MONTH` in `to_char()` returns name of month padded to 9 characters.

Use `fm` prefix as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21035639/1483). See example:

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(to_date('2014-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'month yyyy') MONTH,
  TO_CHAR(to_date('2014-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 'fmmonth yyyy') fmmonth
FROM
  dual;
```